# Git - order of "git branch" changed after renaming branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Out of curiosity.

```
$ git log --oneline
fac0840 (HEAD -> toStringNewFeatureClass) SecondMain - add dupa to toString
c289486 NewFeatureClass toString implementation
ccd48cb (NewFeatureClass) Add NewFeatureClass
fecb127 (master) Remove tmpfile.txt from staging index
```

I renamed one of the branches to NewFeatureClass and it's being shown on the top of the list.

```
$ git branch
  NewFeatureClass
  master
* toStringNewFeatureClass
```

Before renaming the 'git branch' command used to show the branches by creation order, that is NewFeatureClass was created on top of master, toStringNewFeatureClass on top of NewFeatureClass, so they were shown in the following order masterNewFeatureClass, toStringNewFeatureClass.  Why is the order changed?

thanks

Comment: `git branch` should always sort local branch names in (computer-oriented) alphabetical order by default (here all uppercase comes before all lowercase; see http://www.asciitable.com/). So the output you show for `git branch` is correct. You don't show any actual output from before with the wrong order and I am not sure I believe that the output ever was in any other order, especially because Git normally has no ideas about branch creation order.

Answer (score 0):

git branch documentation

> --sort= Sort based on the key given. Prefix - to sort in descending order of the value. You may use the --sort= option
>   multiple times, in which case the last key becomes the primary key.
>   The keys supported are the same as those in git for-each-ref. `Sort
>   order defaults to sorting based on the full refname (including
>   refs/... prefix)`. This lists detached HEAD (if present) first, then
>   local branches and finally remote-tracking branches.